# How do I give access to a Former users Outlook Calendar to another User

Tags: active-directory, calendar, office365, microsoft-outlook-2016

To make a long story short, we have a staff member out for a period of time, and have brought in another employee to fill the currently open position. The former employee had created a calendar within Outlook, that the new hire only has read access to. The new hire needs to be able to read and edit this calendar.

In my research, it would appear that its as easy as having the user login and give Edit Access to the calendar, but I feel like there should be a way to do it through the Admin Console on Office365, I feel like I am missing something glaringly obvious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting up delegation in Office365 would be the better approach versus handing over the account credentials to the other user.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/allow-someone-else-to-manage-your-mail-and-calendar-41c40c04-3bd1-4d22-963a-28eafec25926

Comment: If I understand correctly, Id still need the original user logged in to delegate access to the calendar, right? Without exposing too much personal information, she's out temporarily on Mat Leave, so the User Account still exists for when she returns to work, and we created a new User Account for the new Temp. Hire . The calendar only holds room booking times, but the new employee needs to be able to edit this calendar as cancellations come in for room reservations, etc.

Comment: Oof, just realized SuperUser Rules dont allow for questions in regards to Business Related IT Issues, will remove

Comment: Delegate access should definitely take care of that use case. I didn't realize this forum cannot be used for business IT. Is there a separate forum for that?

Comment: Im not sure either, I just happened to scroll through the Tour Page and saw they typically didn't like to have Business IT or Networking related issues posted in the forum, Id understand for network specific things but for stuff like this im sure its fine. Maybe a Business IT Stack Exchange is in order